# isn't "knowledge society" a concept that is being abstract to ears of most people?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Q: **Isn't the expression ‘knowledge economy or society’ a concept that is in danger of being abstract to the ears of most people?**
>
> A: But the knowledge economy is the one we are already living in. Science and its relationship to society relate to every political issue, such as health, the battle for the environment, education, jobs, food security, energy and transport. We are emerging from a period when power and leadership depended on material resources and entering a knowledge economy. Innovation, research and education are the three factors that cause the economy and society to evolve towards this new paradigm of knowledge. This requires us to change our way of thinking and our approach.

I did not understand the answer. Isn't the knowledge society in danger of being abstract? Yes or no, and please explain why?

Comment: Any theoretical concept is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

The interviewee doesn’t directly say no, but he does so indirectly.

The interviewer starts with the position that the “knowledge economy” is an abstract idea to most people because they don’t see how it will affect them in the future.

The interviewee says that people are *already* living in the “knowledge economy” today and are seeing right now how it is affecting them. In other words, it is already concrete, so talking about it as something abstract or in the future is moot.